# Always getting error "System not responding" in my Emulator

Tags: android-emulator

I am using Emulator. Each and every time when I run app for test, its shows "System not responding".
How can I resolve this error that requires clicking "Wait" around 100 times before being able to work on the emulator?

Clearing ram and cache.